# How to get migration working? Custom DbMigration never gets called from auto-migration; custom system ignored by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

The application I am developing is using code-first approach to create a database from a range of classes representing the different tables, all set up using the corresponding EF attributes.

An example class

```
public class Payment : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string callee = "") => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(callee));
    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;
    protected void RaisePropertyChanging([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string callee = "") => this.PropertyChanging?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangingEventArgs(callee));

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now it gets a new property, eg.

```
public bool Assigned { get; set; }
```

This causes the automatic-migration to attempt to update the classes. The issue now arises when there already is data in the database, causing the migration to fail due to `NOT NULL` constraint being violated here.

I attempted to solve this by adding a custom migration:

```
public class UpgradeToV00002 : DbMigration, System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.IMigrationMetadata
{
    public string Id => this.GetType().FullName;

    public string Source => null;
    public string Target => "2";

    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn(TableName<Payment>(), nameof(Payment.Assigned), (column) => column.Boolean(nullable: false, defaultValue: true));
    }
}
```

The custom migration however is never called. Utilizing a custom versioning system is not working either sadly ...

```
public static void UpgradeFromVersion(Context cntxt, int current, int target)
{
    var migrator = new DbMigrator(new MigrationsConfiguration());

    // Migrate from any version up to current by iterating through migrations
    for (int i = current; i < target; i++)
    {
        var migration = Migrations[i];
        migration.Up();

        // Execute default migrations
        var prop = migration.GetType().GetProperty("Operations", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (prop != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.MigrationOperation> operations = prop.GetValue(migration) as IEnumerable<System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Model.MigrationOperation>;
            var generator = new Npgsql.NpgsqlMigrationSqlGenerator();
            var statements = generator.Generate(operations, new Version(10, 0, 0, 0).ToString());

            foreach (System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.MigrationStatement item in statements)
            {
                cntxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(item.Sql);
            }
        }
    }

    var localMigrations = migrator.GetLocalMigrations();
    var databaseMigrations = migrator.GetDatabaseMigrations();
    var pendingMigrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();

    foreach (var migration in localMigrations.Concat(databaseMigrations).Concat(pendingMigrations))
    {
        cntxt.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(migration);
    }
        
    //////////////////////////////
    // Exception is raised here //
    //////////////////////////////
    migrator.Update();
}
```

The `migrator.Update()` is always attempting to rewrite the database, regardless of what I am trying to do and all, local-, database- and pendingMigrations are always yielding empty results.

If I leave out the call to `migrator.Update()`, the database still attempts to do the migration, failing in the process as the change already got registered in the custom migration.

How should I solve this?

- How can I tell Entity Framework that the database is already updated?
- How can I intercept the migration process for specific versions, relying for most changes on automatic migration and for specific changes, requiring transformations, on actual code-based migrations?

Comment: If you look in the DB, does your _MigrationHistory table reflect any migrations found in your custom created migration list (in your IDE where you coded the migrations yourself)? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

[Customizing Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/#customizing-migrations)

Just let EF generate the scaffolding the way it thinks best, and then modify the migration so your liking.

> Run the Add-Migration AddPostClass command in Package Manager Console.
>
> Code First Migrations did a pretty good job of scaffolding these changes, but there are some things we might want to change:
>
> 1. First up, let’s add a unique index to Posts.Title column (Adding in line 22 & 29 in the code below).
> 2. We’re also adding a non-nullable Blogs.Rating column. If there is any existing data in the table it will get assigned the CLR default of the data type for new column (Rating is integer, so that would be 0). But we want to specify a default value of 3 so that existing rows in the Blogs table will start with a decent rating. (You can see the default value specified on line 24 of the code below)

Comment: I am not really satisfied with this answer. The main goal here is not to use external cmdlets, possibly hiding incompatibilities during development and the need to have specific code written to allow those cmdlets to run (Connection-String is read at server runtime, might change "at random" due to legal-reasons, EF part is in a different project, getting the credentials for the connection string from the server).

Comment: No cmdlet is run on the server. You change the code in Visual Studio. You run the cmdlet in Visual Studio. You take the generated migration code and modify it to your liking, then you commit it to source control. This is how code first migrations work, I suggest you read the full article I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I am well aware of that. The issue still remains the same with heavy lifting being required to read-out the connection string each time some even minor change is done. While this can be circumvented (`Add-Migration AddPostClass -ConnectionString "Username=*****;[...];Port=5432" -ConnectionProviderName Npgsql`) after reading out the current configuration, the rather uncommon way seems to prevent EF to actually work (`System.Data.Entity.Core.ProviderIncompatibleException` being raised).

Comment: I apparently misunderstood your question. I thought your problem could be solved by following the official way of modifying the auto-generated migrations to fit your needs. Now it seems you want to write the migrations yourself completely because you don't want to have to connect to a database in order to create the migration(or at least have to configure the connection). I can't help with the latter, and to be honest I am not sure it is advisable or really less heavy lifting.

Comment: "Providing an actual solution to having Code-First database migration with a way to intercept when transformative changes need to happen or to provide defaults, allowing new non-null columns, to be added." - To be clear, this can all be done by modifying the auto-generated migrations.